# Is there a measurable of entanglement for a many-body system?

Tags: entanglement, experimental-realization, solid-state

After having a discussion with a quantum computing colleague, a question came up: **is there any meaningful way to measure entanglement (or something related to it) in a solid-state many body system where you don't have the luxury of individual qubit control?** Specifically, I am interested in the case of the solid-state, not cold atoms where you can do quite marvelous things at the single qubit level. I suppose there might be various entanglement witnesses out there, but I am wondering which among them is (in-principle) measurable in a real-life solid-state experiment.

To explain what I mean by "meaningful", please not that, as the comments indicate, I acknowledge that measuring the true degree of entanglement of a solid-state system is extremely difficult for fundamental reasons. It is near impossible to put a physical cat into a superposition of two states, for example. However, I would contend that in solid-state systems one is *only interested in low-energy phenomena*, so entanglement is only of interest for a small subset of the total degrees of freedom. For example, core electrons make up the majority of the degrees of freedom in a solid, but play almost no role in most properties. On the other hand, valence electrons are much fewer in number, but dictate most of the interesting chemical and physical properties. So, by "meaningful" measure of entanglement, I mean a method which allows you to ignore the inactive degrees of freedom that don't contribute anything to the physics of the solid-state system of interest.

As an example of the use of such an entanglement measurable, quantum phase transitions are quite interesting in the context of solid-state systems, and are thought to give rise to enormous entanglement among degrees of freedom as one nears the critical point. If one had an experimentally measurable quantity describing the entanglement, one should be able to identify one of the key properties of quantum phase transitions.

A somewhat related question that I posted several years ago about Quantum Fisher Information
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274891/interpreting-the-quantum-fisher-information

Comment: I don't know about entanglement measures for macroscopic systems, but it seems even detecting macroscopic superpositions is difficult see: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.07450.pdf

Comment: Well I think that statement comes from a different viewpoint than what I am thinking. It is normal in solid-state systems to separate out degrees of freedom by energy/length scale. Yes it is very difficult (near impossible) to measure a macroscopic superposition of the center-of-mass position of bulk object, but it is much more straightfoward to put a solid into a superposition of different electronic/vibrational states.

Comment: Even quantum phase transitions only give rise to a **tiny** amount of entanglement, compared to what is possible.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch True, but it is a general fact that most solid-state phenomena (transistors, diodes, superconductivity) only involve a very tiny amount of electrons/degrees-of-freedom compared to the total possible. Despite this, you still are talking about way more DOF/entanglement compared to single atoms/qubits though. I think my question is still of practical importance and meaningful to ask in any case.

Comment: @user157879 There is quite a body of literature on entanglement and quantum phase transitions. And on entanglement in many-body systems. Your question is rather broad. What do you mean by "meaningful"? How is the short question you ask at the beginning related to the discussion you give afterwards?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I have edited the question to elaborate on your points. I guess what I am trying to stress is that it is certainly too hard to study the "full-degree" of entanglement in a solid-state system overall since you can't construct complete superpositions (as Condo points out). But are there other quantities which are "entanglement witnesses" in many-body systems that are (in principle) experimentally measurable and don't require sophisticated quantum control at the qubit level?

Comment: I think the question as it stands is just too broad. It is not clear what would be a good answer, and it feels there are plenty of implicit wishes there. In principle vs. practical, many-body vs. condensed matter, ...  People have been measuring various entanglement measures in optical lattices, for instance. One can define entanglement measures which tell you a lot about the physics but are harder to measure (but still in principle measurable). And so forth ...

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I have tried to rewrite the question again based on your criticisms. Yes, entanglement measures in optical lattices are what partially inspired me to ask this question. I was wondering if similar things can be done in solid-state systems where things are messy and you have a lot more degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed becoming more clear! Do you care about preparing a state with much entanglement, or just a measurement which will quantify or bound the amount of a certain type of entanglement (like a witness), even if the result in a condensed matter system could be "no entanglement" (or "very little ent.")?  (BTW, in "measurable of entanglement"/"entanglement measurable", do you mean "measure"?)